# Format awk output with appending to existing file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a command in awk: `awk -F, '{$1=sprintf("%.2f",$1*value)}1' value=$VALUE OFS=, input.txt` doing multiplication on first column from the input file:

```
2097160    /home/x/a/c/2GB/
102408     /home/y/b/d/100MB/
...
```

The output is:

```
0.66
0.03
...
```

What I want is to append the above output as a last column to another file delimited by tab and preceded with dollar sign `$` to make it looking like:

```
2.1G    /home/x/a/c/2GB/                    $0.66
101M    /home/y/b/d/100MB/                  $0.03
...
```

How can I do this without creating a multiple files etc?

Comment: That can't be the output of the script you are showing on those input files. Shouldn't your output also have the paths? Please [edit] your question and show us all relevant input files (including the tab separated one) and then the output you expect from these inputs.

Comment: Your sample input file is space separated and the awk scrip you posted sets FS to `,` to work on comma-separated input so clearly the script you posted is wrong or the sample input is wrong, please fix your example to be consistent and accurate. Also, tell us what `$VALUE` is set to.

Answer (score 1):

I made these files to use as input:

```
$ cat file1
2097160    /home/x/a/c/2GB/
102408     /home/y/b/d/100MB/
$ cat file1
2097160    /home/x/a/c/2GB/
102408     /home/y/b/d/100MB/
```

Then, I simply modified your script so that it reads both files and, while it is reading the first one (while the current file's record number FNR is the same as the input record number, NR), it will save the result of the multiplication in an array whose indices are the paths:

```
$ awk '(NR==FNR){a[$2]=sprintf("%.2f",$1*value); next} {print $1,$2,a[$2]}' OFS="\t" value=0.000000315 file1 file2
2.1G    /home/x/a/c/2GB/    0.66
101M    /home/y/b/d/100MB/  0.03
```

Comment: Thanks @terdon, how can I add multiple tabs between second and third column?

Answer (score 1):

For fun, a perl one-liner using the [Number::Bytes::Human](https://metacpan.org/pod/Number::Bytes::Human) module:

```bsh
perl -MNumber::Bytes::Human=format_bytes -slane '
    printf "%s\t%s\t\$%.2f\n",
        format_bytes($F[0] * 1024),
        $F[1],
        $value * $F[0]
' -- -value=0.000000315 file
```

```
2.1G    /home/x/a/c/2GB/    $0.66
101M    /home/y/b/d/100MB/  $0.03
```

Comment: just remove the newlines in the quoted string.